# Show that if $p$ is a prime number and $a$ is an integer, and if $p \mid a^2$ , then $p \mid a$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, square-numbers

I am suppose to make use of the following lemma

> If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive integers such that $(a, \, b) = 1$ and $a \mid bc$, then $a \mid c$

to prove that if $p$ is a prime number and $a$ is an integer, and if $p \mid  a^2$ , then $p \mid a$.

I'm not sure how the lemma helps. I could write $a^2 = aa$ with $b=c=a$ in the lemma but we don't have $(a,b)=(p,a)=1$ so I don't see how it would help. I must use this lemma to prove it. I am aware that there are other methods.

Comment: How is prime defined?

Comment: @AaronMaroja An integer $> 1$ with no divisors except one and itself.

Comment: Hint: If $p$ divides $a$ we are finished. Otherwise, $p$ and $a$ are relatively prime and we can apply the lemma.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah, I see, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.  If $d\gt 1$ divides $p$ and $a$, then in particular $d$ divides $a$, so $d=p$.

Comment: See also: [A short or elegant proof for if $p \mid n^2$ then $p \mid n$ when $p$ is prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/546498), [A quick question about: If $p$ is prime show that $p\mid a^2 \implies p\mid a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1916497), [$p$ prime, $p\mid a^k \Rightarrow p^k\mid a^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/881779), [If $p$ is prime and $p \mid a^k$, then $p \mid a$, and hence $p^k \mid a^k$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2571635)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By contradiction: Given $p \mid a^2$, if $p\nmid a$ and since $p$ is prime then $(p,a)=1$ so using the mentioned result we get $p \mid a$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose $p$ does **not** divide $a$ then $(p,a) =1$ and now you may apply your lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $p| a^2$ but $p\not| a$. Note that $(p,a)$ divides $p$, so $(p,a)=1$ or $p$. Also, $(p,a)$ divides $a$, and  $p\not| a$, so $(p,a)=1$. Then apply your lemma.