# Proving that if two integers have opposite parity, then their product is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

If two integers have opposite parity, then their product is even.

Proof Method: Direct Proof

If two integers have opposite parity, then one is even and the other is odd.

Suppose: $a$ is an even integer and $b$ is an odd integer, then by definition of even and odd integers

$$a = 2m, \quad b = 2n+1,$$ while $m$ and $n$ are integers.

$$ ab = 2m(2n+1)= 4mn+2m = 2(2mn+m)
$$
Let $c = 2mn+m$ be an integer, then $ab=2c$ is even

Therefore, the product of two opposite parity integers is even

Thank You!

Comment: One suggestion for improvement:  Prove that $2mn + m$ is an integer.  Since $2, m, n$ are integers and the product of integers is an integer, $2mn$ is an integer.  Since $2mn$ and $m$ are integers and the sum of integers is an integer, $2mn + m$ is an integer.

Comment: For anyone visiting from Stack Overflow who is as confused as I was at first, [parity in mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_\(mathematics\)) is not the same as [parity in computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit). In math, parity is whether an integer is even or odd. In computing, parity is whether _the number of `1` bits in the binary representation of the integer_ is even or odd. For example, in computing, `3` is binary `11` with even parity. `7` is binary `111` with odd parity. And their product, `21`, is binary `10101`, so it is both odd and has odd parity.

Comment: Another, possible proof would be : `Duh`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes of course that's correct.

We can also observe that

- if $a\in \mathbb{N}$ is even $\implies 2\,|\,a\,$ and $\,\forall b \in \mathbb{N} \quad 2\,|\,ab \implies ab$ is
  even.

Comment: Use **\mid** for for better spacing of the divisibility symbol $\mid$. For example, instead of $2|ab$, you could generate $2\mid ab$. Notice the better spacing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I fix it!

Comment: No problem :) ${}$

Answer (score 4):

*Euclid's Lemma* asserts that if a prime number $p$ divides the product $ab$ of two integers $a$ and $b$, then $p$ must divide at least one of those integers $a$ and $b$.

Since $2$ is a prime number, we can let $p = 2$. We now want to show that for integers $a$ and $b$ that have an opposite parity, $2$ must divide the product $ab$.

When two numbers have an opposite parity, then one of those numbers is even and the remaining number is odd. The definition of an even number is such that the number is divisible by $2$. The contrary is the definition of an odd number. This is why we let $p = 2$ in the first place.

Since either $a$ or $b$ must be even, the remaining integer consequently being odd, then $2$ must divide either $a$ or $b$. Therefore, $2$ must also divide $ab$ which makes that product an even number.

Go [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581173/proof-of-euclids-lemma) for a proof of Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: -1: you are not using "Euclid's lemma" at all. You are using its converse (if one of a or b is even then ab is even), which is almost trivially true.

Comment: @TashiWalde Yes sorry. I forgot to add *why* we let $p = 2$. Otherwise, you are correct.