# Help to understand a simple statement in elementary proof of the euclidean theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Well, I found an elementary proof for the Euclidean theorem from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1471135) :

It was okay until I got stuck in $x*b=qx_0b+rb$ :

"Indeed, let $x\in E$. We have $x=qx_0+r$ for a unique pair $(q,r)\enspace (0\le r<x_0)$. As $p$ divides $xb$ and $x_ob$, $p$ divides $xb-qx_0b=rb$"

I need to be more rigorously, but I didn't understand why $p$ divides $xb-qx_0b=rb$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $p$ divides $xb$ and $x_0b$, there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $xb=pm$ and $x_0b=pn$. Then

$$xb-qx_0b=pm-qpn=p(m-qn)\,,$$

where $m-qn$ is an integer, so $p$ divides $xb-qx_0b$.