# Prove that $2\sqrt 5$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $2\sqrt 5$ is irrational

**My attempt:**

Suppose $$2\sqrt 5=\frac p q\quad\bigg/()^2$$

$$\Longrightarrow 4\cdot 5=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$$

$$\Longrightarrow 20\cdot q^2=p^2$$

$$\Longrightarrow q\mid p^2$$

$$\text{gcd}(p,q)=1$$

$$\Longrightarrow \text{gcd}(p^2,q)=1$$

How can I procced?

Comment: Hint: $16q^2 + 4q^2=p^2$ has no integer solution by Fermat's last theorem.

Comment: I did not learn yet this theorem

Comment: @user319071, If  $20|p^2$ we can't immediately say that $20|p$ and in general it is not true for composite numbers. $20|p^2$, thus $2|p^2$ and $5|p^2$, hence $2|p\wedge 5|p$, hence $10|p$. For example $20|100$, but $20$ doesn't divide $10$.

Comment: Remark that $2\sqrt{5}$ is rational if and only if $\sqrt{5}$ is rational and then go see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451700/prove-that-sqrt-5-is-irrational?rq=1).

Comment: @Nehorai Teachers don't teach Fermat's last theorem. Its a proof that took 358 years to be proven and hence made the proof quite famous especially as it was only published in 1994-95. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem

Comment: @user319071 How does Fermat's Last Theorem prove that $16q^2 + 4q^2 = p^2$ has no solutions?

Comment: Using Fermat here would be like using a nuclear warhead to open a soda can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2\sqrt5 = \frac pq, \gcd (p,q=1)$$
$$20q^2=p^2 \Rightarrow 5|p^2 \Rightarrow 5|p \Rightarrow 25|p^2$$
Let $p=5p_1$
$$20q^2=25p_1^2 \Rightarrow 5|q $$
$$\gcd (p,q)\geq 5$$
Сontradiction.

Answer (score 2):

You have $20|p^2$, thus $2|p^2\wedge 5|p^2$, hence by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma) $2|p\wedge 5|p$, hence $10|p$, so we can write $p=10k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and then $20q^2=100k^2\Rightarrow q^2=5k^2$, hence $5|q^2$, and by the same lemma $5|q$, thus $\text{gcd}(p,q)=5$, so we got a contradiction.

Comment: (+1) for the effort, I did not learn this lemma yet

Comment: Do you know how to show that $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational without this lemma? Please notice that Roman83 answer also uses it.

Comment: I have a proof for $\sqrt 2$ in my textbook

Comment: And this sketch of proof will hold for any number which is not a perfect square, but it uses the mentioned lemma.

Comment: You used Euclid's lemma in your question.