# Prove that $\sqrt3/\sqrt2$ is irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can i prove that $\sqrt3/\sqrt2$ is irrational?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you know how to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational?

Comment: Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688283/prove-that-sqrt5-5-is-irrational?rq=1).

Comment: Yes i know how to prove this.

Comment: Otherwise $3n^2 = 2m^2$, $m,n$ coprime, so that $n$ is even. But then $12p^2 = 2m^2$, or $6p^2 = m^2$ implies $m$ is even, so they're not coprime, contradiction

Answer (score 4):

If $\sqrt{3}/\sqrt2=m/n$ ($m$ and $n$ positive integers) then
$$
3n^2=2m^2.
$$
But that is impossible, because the prime decomposition of the rhs contains an odd number of $2$, while on the lhs there is an even number of $2$.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer please.

Comment: In the prime decomposition of a square number, all prime factors are repeated an even number of times (including 0 times, of course). But on the right hand side there is an additional factor of 2, which is not present on the left hand side.

Comment: Thank you but please what does mean odd number of 2 and even number of 2 is that mean : (2k) and (2k+1) but i cant see "of 2" meaning would you clarify that ?

Comment: $2\cdot2\cdot2$ is a product with an odd number of 2's, $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2$ is a product with an even number of 2's.

Answer (score 4):

If $\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}$ is rational then so is its double, $\sqrt6$.

$\sqrt6$ is the root of $x^2-6$, and by the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) the only possible rational roots of this polynomial are $\left\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm6\right\}$, none of which are roots.

Comment: The "doubling" is equivalent to applying the [AC-method](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/647116/242) to $\,2x^2 -3\,$ to obtain the monic $\,X^2 -6,\,$ for $\,X = 2x.\ $

Comment: Of course, we can simply apply the Rational Root Theorem to $2x^2-3$ and get $\left\{\pm\frac12,\pm1,\pm\frac32,\pm3\right\}$. However, it seemed so much easier to verify that the the integers in the list did not satisfy $x^2-6=0$.

Comment: Right, but my point was to show readers how your idea of scaling to integral roots generalizes to arbitrary polynomials (a simple yet frequently useful method deserves to be better known).

Answer (score 0):

We prove by method of contradiction. Suppose the given no sqrt(3)/sqrt(2) is rational. Try rationalising the denominator sqrt(2) by sqrt(2). Then we get the no to be of the form sqrt(6)/2 which is rational by our assumption. Thus 2×(sqrt(6))/2 =sqrt(6) is also rational as product of two rational is again rational i.e sqrt(6) is rational which is a contradiction. This is due to our assumption that sqrt(3(/sqrt(2) is rational. Hence our assumption is wrong and so it is irrational