# Prove that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{17}$ is irrational. Is my proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification

1. $2+17  = a^2/b^2$
2. $19b^2 = a^2$   ($a$ is divisible by 19)
3. $19b^2 = (19k)^2$
4. $19b^2 = 361k^2$
5. $b^2 = 19k$     ($b$ is divisible by 19)

Since both numbers are divisible by 19,it means they have a common factor.

Is this accurate? If not,please elaborate. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you arrive at the first line $2+17=a^2/b^2$? Please do not say, by squaring both sides of $\sqrt 2+\sqrt{17}=a/b$

Comment: Yes, your proof is incorrect. $\sqrt{2+17}\neq \sqrt{17}+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Looks like you have fallen for the  "Freshman's dream."

Comment: Any advice? :'l

Comment: Think about the rational root theorem as applied to $(x-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{17})(x-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17})(x+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{17})(x+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17})=0$

Comment: Alternatively, start with $\frac{a}{b} = \sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{17}$, square both sides (correctly!) and simplify to get a contradiction where a square root of a nonsquare must be rational.

Comment: What am i messing up with the squaring of both of the sides?

Comment: What a number of the posts are referring to is the "Freshman's dream", the mistaken belief that $(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n$. You do this when you say that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17}=a/b$, and then square both sides, but this is incorrect. Consider, for example, $(2+3)^2=5^2=25$. The freshman's dream would tell us that $(2+3)^2=2^2+3^2=13$, which is wrong. You need to just evaluate $(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2$ by FOILing.

Comment: @user569685. 
It's not the case that $(a+b)^2= a^2+b^2$. Though it kind of looks like it might be that. It's a common error. You can see it quickly though... Let $a=b=1$. It is however the case $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and that should help.

Answer (score 1):

As already noticed in the comments, assume that $\exists q\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that

$$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{17}=q \implies (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{17})^2=q^2$$

$$2+17+2\sqrt{34}=q^2 \implies \sqrt{34}=\frac{q^2-19}2\in \mathbb{Q}$$

which is a contradiction, see for that the related

- [Proving $\sqrt 3$ is irrational.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131391/505767)
- [Prove that $\sqrt 5$ is irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/451700/505767)

Comment: You have dropped a $2$. Must be $2\sqrt{34}$

Comment: @Mason Opssss...thanks I've fixed that :)

Comment: And why is it a contradiction that $\sqrt{34}$ is rational? The proof of this is an analog of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451700/prove-that-sqrt-5-is-irrational?rq=1)

Comment: @Mason Yes that's a classical proof, I add that! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but your argument is incorrect. From
$$
\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17}=\frac{a}{b}
$$
and squaring, you get
$$
2 + 2\sqrt{34} + 17=\frac{a^2}{b^2}
$$
and not $19=a^2/b^2$ as you claimed.

---

You can instead observe that
$$
\frac{(\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{17}-\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{17}-\sqrt{2}}=\frac{a}{b}
\tag{*}
$$
which is tantamount as saying that
$$
\sqrt{17}-\sqrt{2}=\frac{15b}{a}
\tag{**}
$$
Subtracting (**) from (*) you get
$$
2\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{15b}{a}
$$
which would imply that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational.

Note that this method will work in all instances of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{x}$ (so long as $x\ne2$).